# Simulation with RK4, update ODE variable as the simulation goes

Tags: python, matplotlib, real-time, ode, runge-kutta

#### Problem :

I’m currently making a python app that simulates a set of coupled ordinary differentials equations that depends on a variable, let’s call it « X ».

As for now, I’m basically simulating this set of ODE with RK4 for given time then I’m plotting the graph on an animated plot with « matplotlib animation » embedded in tkinter.

The fact is that I would like to be able to modify « X » as the equations are resolved so that the simulation can change as we modify this variable.

#### Context :

The solution changes from that time on. To put things in context, these are the equations for the xenon and iodine abundance as well as neutrons flow in a nuclear reactor. The variable that change is "big sigma_b" that governs the control bars.

#### ODE :

*xenon and iodine abundance ODE* : 
[image: xenon and iodine abundance ODEe]

*neutrons flow ODE* :
[image: neutrons flow ODE]

#### Summary :

To summarize, « X » belongs to the range [1.0, 2.0], let’s say we want to run 400 hours of simulations :

- We launch the simulation of ODE
- We update the animated plot every second (which is equal to 1 hour of simulation on the graph)
- We modify « X » with the help of a slider for instance (in fact "X" is not directly modified, there is a dynamic process that progressively move the initial "X" value toward its chosen value).
- The RK4 algorithm take that into account
- We can see that change on the updated graph
- etc…
- When the simulation is finished, we stop the plot updating

Hopefully, it’s clear enough.
How could I do that ?

Comment: So you have a time variable that has hours as unit. Every second you integrate the segment corresponding to one hour, update the animation, usually waiting a lot of time as the integration is fast. Then on the slider change, the solution changes completely from the start or from that time on?

Comment: The solution changes from that time on.
To put things in context, these are the equations for the xenon and iodine abundance as well as neutrons flow in a nuclear reactor. The variable that change is "sigma_b" that governs the control bars.

Comment: So your X is changed by the dynamic process *and* by the slider? Or do you take it out of the dynamic and treat it as piecewise constant? But that would make also no sense, as X does not influence the other equations.

Comment: At the beginning, we have an initial flow of 1e10 and "Sigma_b" has an initial value between 1.0 and 2.0. Let's say 1.0 for instance. Then, the dynamic process tend to modify the value of "Sigma_b" so the flow can be stabilized at a value of 1e15. 
However, we should also be able to modify "Sigma_b" by moving a slider to see what happens next.

The ultimate goal is to recreate what happened at Tchernobyl.

Comment: You mean to recreate the story as told after the filter of soviet and western propaganda replaced parts of it. // I still think it not very realistic to manipulate the value of a dynamical variable, as that would be like adding Dirac-deltas to the ODE function. If the dynamic process regulates Sigma_b towards some equilibrium, then it would be more realistic to manipulate parameters of this regulation process that determine the equilibrium position.

Comment: Well, I think it makes sense. How could I do that in "real time" ?

Comment: What I think could work: For the interface, follow the documentation example linked in the question or the one in the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/q/36762510/3088138. The slider event function sets a flag that the value has changed. The animation update function checks that flag to set the state variable to the value of the slider, and resets the flag. Then perform the step and set the line data of the graphs.

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna check that and give it a try. I'll keep you updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translating the ideas of the comments into a mockup gives some code to experiment with

[image]

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider
import matplotlib.animation as anim
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint

# model is dampened oscillation with control variable u 
# representing the equilibrium position
# x'' + 0.4*x + x == u

def model(x,u): return np.array([x[1], u - 0.4*x[1] - x[0]])

# integrate over about 10 periods
N=250
t = np.linspace(0, 12*np.pi,  N+1)              # time
# arrays to hold the computed values
X = np.zeros([N+1,2])
U = np.zeros([N+1])
# initial values
X[0] = [3, 2]          
U[0] = 2;

# initialize plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.25, bottom=0.25)
# initialize graphs
l1, = plt.plot(t[0], X[0,0], '-+b', ms=2 )
l2, = plt.plot(t[0], U[0], '-or', ms=2, lw=1 )
plt.xlim(t[0], t[-1]); plt.ylim(-1,3)

# construct slider
axcolor = 'black'
ax_U = plt.axes([0.25, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03], facecolor=axcolor)
sU = Slider(ax_U, 'U', 1.0, 2.0, valinit=U[0])


def animate(i):
    # read the slider value
    U[i] = sU.val
    # integrate over the sub-interval
    X[i] = odeint(lambda x,t: model(x,U[i]), X[i-1], [t[i-1],t[i]], atol=1e-4, rtol=1e-8)[-1];
    # set the data to plot
    l1.set_data(t[0:i+1],X[0:i+1,0]);
    l2.set_data(t[0:i+1],U[0:i+1]);
    return l1,l2

# start the animation, one should set the parameter to keep it from repeating
anim = anim.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames = range(1,N+1), blit=True, interval = 100 )
plt.show()
```